# E appearing in Regression table

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, logarithm

I am trying to run a regression between oil price in the US over a 60 year period and REAL GDP. I have run a simple linear regression (I also do not know if this is appropriate or not--should I be running a different type of regression?). -- should I include more vairables, should this be a multiple-regression?

In my ANOVA results table my SS and significance F display "E" in the output e.g. my regression SS is 1.06038E+15. I have no idea what this means or where to find information on it.

If anoyone can explain, or has any advice on how I should conduct this regression I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You question is too broad, but my advise is to start by looking at the data at hand. Study the relation between the variables and look for possible non linear relationships. Linear regression may be a good strat, but you may consider other regression models s.t. quantile regression. Which method is more useful very much depends on your aim.

Comment: The software that you are using is displaying the sum of squares (and maybe the p-value too) using the [e notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). E.g., 1E1 = 10, 1E-1 = 0.1 etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation ... most people learn scientific notation in science class at school and this version of scientific notation is almost standard on calculators (only a few kinds do anything else). I just picked up my phone and calculated $9^{58}$  on the calculator app it came with (I have not had occasion to use it before); the answer it gave was in E-notation.

Comment: Many questions on site address this issue.